# Photoshop: Can I save a list of fixed ratios for future use?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, crop

When using Photoshop, I often use the Fixed Ratio selection tool to create images with exact sizes, for Facebook, Twitter, Blogs, Featured Images, etc.

I've been looking for a way (or plugin) to make a selection list of Fixed Ratio widths and heights that I often use, so I don't need to re-enter (and remember) them every time I want to create such an image.

Does anyone know a plugin, or some feature in Photoshop that I've completely overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Tool Preset` for it.

You can always find the tool specific presets on the very left of the tool options bar:

[image]

1. Change the tool settings
2. Use this dropdown to create a new preset
3. Use this dropdown to select a preset to use.

> Some tools allow selecting specific things to save in the preset, while others don't. If PS doesn't let you choose when you create the preset *(when you start naming it)* then it just saves every value. This makes presets a little stiff to use sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Joonas mentioned Tool Presets, however they won't save ratios for `Selection Tool`. Yet here's what you can do:

- if you crop your images later, save tool presets of a `Crop Tool` with specified ratios/sizes;
- you can create several [`Actions`](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) for each ratio using the `Selection Tool` with specific selection sizes.

Comment: The preset tool does save the ratios here (Photoshop CC 20.0.2). But nevertheless I'm glad you pointed out the crop tool too. I have a whole Photoshop-world to discover!

Comment: Oh, I missed that option! so Joonas was right. So many things to discover indeed :)